# Using spatial buffer to "declutter" and retain point data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, buffer, geoprocessing

I have a shapefile of point data (lat/lon points) that I need to "declutter" a bit, based on a 15 km spatial buffer around each point. The image below shows what the data points look like, along with the 15 km spatial buffer I added around each point.

I need to remove some of the point data from this shapefile while retaining the maximum number of original point data locations possible (each with a 15 km buffer around them), and removing the minimum number of points.

[image]

I'm using ArcMap 10.7.1. I've tried using the Integrate (Data Management) tool, which will retain the point data locations already >15km from other points, but creates new integrated point data locations based on the original points that are <15km from others.

How do I retain the maximum number of the actual point data locations?

Comment: Are you still looking for solution?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking.

Comment: My solution involves python, are you open to it?

Comment: Yes, that's fine with me. Thanks